# How to chop a string to substrings of given length

Tags: f#

I have string that I want to chop to array of substrings of given length n. I am not interested in remainder (if length of string cannot be divided by n without remainder)

```
let ChopString (myString : string) n = 
    let res = 
        seq{ 
            for i = 0 to myString.Length / n - 1 do
                yield( String.sub myString (i*n) n )
            }    
        |> Seq.to_array
    res
```

This is the best I could do. It looks ugly to me.

Is there nicer/shorter version of this, maybe without for loop?

Comment: Do you need to break nicely on word boundries?  From your sample code I'd guess "no", but I want to be sure.

Comment: No, I just want to split string to substrings of given length, starting on the beginning of the string - don't care about contents, don't care about any remainder that is shorter than given substring length

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`stringInstance.[start..end]` is much more readable than `String.sub`. Here's what I came up with:

```
    let chop (input : string) len = 
        seq { for start in 0 .. len .. input.Length - 1
            do yield input.[start..start + len - 1] }
        |> Seq.toArray
```

Or you can use:

```
    let chop (input : string) len = 
        Array.init (input.Length / len) (fun index ->
            let start = index * len
            input.[start..start + len - 1])
```

Comment: I like second one more, no loop, no yield, function for initialization. Although intervention on my example is also nice - looks more readable.

Answer (score 0):

[Craig Stunz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7714/craig-stuntz) left answer here that is now missing. Anyway, he pointed to [article about F#](http://microsoft.apress.com/asptodayarchive/74014/introducing-f) that have two functions for string manipulation: `explode` and `implode`. These two functions are from standard ML library. Here's the code:

```
let rec explode str = 
       let len = String.length str in
           if len=0 then [] else 
              (String.sub str 0 1) :: explode (String.sub str 1 (len-1)) 

let rec implode lst = match lst with
                         []  -> ""
                       | x1 :: x2 -> x1 ^ implode x2
```

`explode` chops string into string list where each string is one character.
`implode` does opposite - concatenates string list into one string.
Both functions are recursive, so it would be interesting to compare performance.